# The string methods in Java that use regular expressions don't issue any errors with dots as done with other special characters. Why?

Tags: java

The string methods in Java that use the regular expressions need to escape some special characters like `[`, `(`, `*`, `$`, `+`, `\`, `.` and so on. For example, lets consider the `split()` method. The following expressions will cause the run time exception `java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException`.

```
String str="Java[language";

String arr[]=str.split("[");
```

---

```
String str="Java(language";

String arr[]=str.split("(");
```

---

```
String str="Java*language";

String arr[]=str.split("*");
```

---

```
String str="Java$language";

String arr[]=str.split("$");
```

---

```
String str="Java+language";

String arr[]=str.split("+");
```

---

All the above expressions cause the exception `java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException` obviously because we need them to escape something like this `String arr[]=str.split("\\[");`. That's quite obvious.

---

In case of dot `"."`, however the compiler silently parses it means that the expression `String arr[]=str.split(".");` causes no error, no warning or no exception at all even though its also the part of regular expressions and needs to be escaped. Why? *(The string held by `str` will not be split in this case as obvious)*.

Comment: The compiler doesn't parse it. A pattern is compiled at runtime.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`"."` is a completely valid regular expression that matches any single character.

Comment: Screen-full of question, and a complete answer in just one short sentence. +1.